# I'm stuck trying to add Quilljs to a Rails 5.1 app via Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, quill, yarnpkg

I have been trying to add Quill editor to my app but it doesn't work.

1. I created a Rails 5.1 app with `--webpack` and then I ran `rails webpacker:install`
2. I ran `yarn add quill` and `rails webpacker:compile`
3. I added `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` to *layouts/application.html.erb*
4. In *packs/application.js* I have:

   `import Quill from 'quill';`

   `var quill = new Quill('#article_content', {
   theme: 'snow'
   });`
5. In *_form.html.erb*:

   `<%= form.text_field :content, id: :article_content %>`
6. I ran `rails s` and `.bin/webpack-dev-server`
7. In console i get an error: `quill Invalid Quill container #article_content`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you figure out your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are using Turbolinks too. You need to make sure that you are wrapping the following script with:

```
   document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
     var quill = new Quill('#article_content', {
     theme: 'snow'
     });
   })
```

This solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear when _form.html.erb is being included but that error means when `new Quill` was run, there was no DOM element on the page that matched the input query. Specifically for your case, that means there was no element on the page that has an ID article_content.

Answer (score 0):

```
var quill = new Quill('#article_content', {
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

You can not use a css id selector here, just class works. So change `id="article_content"` to `class="article_content"` ad then your snippet to:

```
var quill = new Quill('.article_content', {
  theme: 'snow'
});
```

and you are ready to go.